# Longer Nodemailer Html/Text

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, nodemailer

Every example of nodemailer is something along these lines:

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: "Fred Foo ✔ <foo@blurdybloop.com>", // sender address
    to: "bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world ✔", // plaintext body
    html: "<b>Hello world ✔</b>" // html body}
```

I want to make a longer message than a one liner when someone signs up.

Is there a way to write and source html from another place within my application, so maybe just a series of line breaks.

**TL;DR**

I want to have nodemailer send a longer email than a one liner

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing here, but don't text and html both just get assigned a string?  Why can't you just assign a longer string to a variable and input that?  Or even inline if you have to?

Comment: Example - `var myString = 'some really long string representing html </br> some other line </br> more etc'`  
  
...  
  
`text: myString`

Comment: If you're using SendGrid then you can store templates inside their system and have Nodemailer just pass any replacement values you want. Details here: https://sendgrid.com/blog/migrating-app-sendgrids-template-engine/

Answer (score 1):

Put the content in a file and then load it.

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('/wwwroot/includes/email.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var html = data;
});
```